# How do I do a full outer join in data tables with multiple keys?

Tags: r, data.table

There are existing answers for how to do outer joins using the `[]` syntax with data tables, but they do not address how to do that with multiple keys.

These are my datasets

```
    A <- data.table(key_a=rep(1:2, 3), key_b = rep(c("blue", "orange", "purple"), 2), 
                    id=rep(11:13), chair = c("green", "red", "green", rep("red", 3)))[, 
            .(join_key = paste0(key_a, key_b), key_a, key_b, id, chair)] 
    B <- A[, .(key_a = key_a + 1, key_b, id, chair)][,
             .(join_key = paste0(key_a, key_b), key_a, key_b, id, chair)]
```

I'd like to create this output

```
        key_a     key_b     chair      id   i.id 
    1:      1      blue     green      NA     11 
    2:      1    orange       red      NA     12 
    3:      1    purple     green      NA     13 
    4:      2      blue     green      11     NA 
    5:      2      blue       red      NA     11 
    5:      2    orange       red      12     12 
    6:      2    purple       red      NA     13 
    7:      2      blue     green      13     NA    
    7:      3      blue       red      11     NA     
    8:      3    orange       red      12     NA     
    9:      3    purple       red      13     NA
```

I tried solving it with this code

```
    unique_keys <- c(A[,join_key], B[,join_key])
    Aprime <- A[.(unique_keys), on= .(join_key)]
    setkey(Aprime, key_a, key_b, join_key, chair)
    
    B[Aprime, on = .(key_a), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

I'd like to use the `[]` syntax because I'd like to make the change on reference to A without making a new object

Comment: Can I do this with the `[]` style? My ultimate goal is to run the join on reference so that I don't need to make a new object

Comment: That's a very good point. Is `[]` faster than `merge` even with making a new object? I'm very concerned about speed

Comment: Can you please post your suggestion as an answer so I can mark it complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at `getAnywhere('merge.data.table')` to see the source code of the `merge` method for `data.table`s -- the method is built using `[`. Follow the logic for the case of `all=TRUE` to see what happens when using `merge`:

```
outer_join = merge(B, A, all=TRUE, by=c('key_a', 'key_b'))
```

Essentially this will do:

1. `B[A, nomatch=NA]` to left join `B` to `A`
2. `B[!A]` to anti-join `B` to `A` (finding the `B` rows now found in `A`, that would be missing from the left join)
3. `rbind` the outputs from 1. and 2. to complete the outer join

The last step is what makes this impossible to do "by-reference" like a join-and-update is often recommended for `data.table` -- we can update *existing rows* and *new/existing columns* for a `data.table` by reference, but we can not add *new rows* by reference.